# inline-list bootstrap multiline text interrupting row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code 
HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1840309" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Divergent" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1840309" class="movie_title">
            Divergent
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2109248" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Transformers: Age of Extinction" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2109248" class="movie_title">
            Transformers: Age of Extinction
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2039393" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="The Gambler" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2039393" class="movie_title">
            The Gambler
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2908446" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Insurgent" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2908446" class="movie_title">
            Insurgent
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2015
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1399103" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Transformers: Dark of the Moon" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1399103" class="movie_title">
            Transformers: Dark of the Moon
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2011
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1620719" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Dabangg" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1620719" class="movie_title">
            Dabangg
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2010
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1099212" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Twilight" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1099212" class="movie_title">
            Twilight
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2008
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1259571" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="The Twilight Saga: New Moon" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1259571" class="movie_title">
            The Twilight Saga: New Moon
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2009
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2338151" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="PK" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2338151" class="movie_title">
            PK
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2713180" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Fury" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2713180" class="movie_title">
            Fury
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2446042" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Taken 3" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2446042" class="movie_title">
            Taken 3
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=3280916" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="The Atticus Institute" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=3280916" class="movie_title">
            The Atticus Institute
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2015
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1780798" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Clown" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1780798" class="movie_title">
            Clown
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1535109" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Captain Phillips" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1535109" class="movie_title">
            Captain Phillips
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2013
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0162222" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Cast Away" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0162222" class="movie_title">
            Cast Away
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2000
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0362227" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="The Terminal" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0362227" class="movie_title">
            The Terminal
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2004
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0120363" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Toy Story 2" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0120363" class="movie_title">
            Toy Story 2
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               1999
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0808151" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Angels & Demons" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0808151" class="movie_title">
            Angels & Demons
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2009
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0435761" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Toy Story 3" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0435761" class="movie_title">
            Toy Story 3
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2010
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1673434" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn - Part 2" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1673434" class="movie_title">
            The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn - Part 2
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2012
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0337692" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="On the Road" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0337692" class="movie_title">
            On the Road
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2012
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2582846" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="The Fault in Our Stars" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=2582846" class="movie_title">
            The Fault in Our Stars
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1587310" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Maleficent" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1587310" class="movie_title">
            Maleficent
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2014
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0114709" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Toy Story" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=0114709" class="movie_title">
            Toy Story
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               1995
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie_item col-xs-6">
         <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1905041" class="movie_link">
            <figure><img class="img-responsive" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ1NDk3NTk0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTk3MDcxMzE@._V1_SY255_CR0,0,170,255.jpg" alt="Fast & Furious 6" /></figure>
         </a>
         <div class="movie_bottom">
            <a href="Movie.php?MovieID=1905041" class="movie_title">
            Fast & Furious 6
            </a>
            <div class="movie_year">
               2013
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
body {
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    color: #6FA5FD;
    font-weight: bold;
}
/*.movie_title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden
}*/
/*figure {
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
}*/
.movie_item {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.movie_bottom {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    max-width: 180px;
    text-align: left
}
.movie_link figure img {
    max-height:255px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .movie_link {
        display: inline-block;
        max-width: 180px;
    }
    .movie_bottom {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .movie_item {
        width: 20%;
    }
    .movie_bottom {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    .img-responsive {
        width: 110px;
        height: 165px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .movie_item {
        width: 25%;
        padding: 0px 31px;
    }
    .img-responsive {
        width: 170px;
        height: 255px;
    }
    .movie_bottom {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .movie_item {
        width: 20%;
        padding: 0px 27px;
    }
}
```

this also requires bootstrap.css

The problem with this code is when title is on two line, the list is broken below that movie, this does not happen for last element in row, in this code's output 3rd row's first movie's title is of 2 lines, the expected movie item below it is missing and pushed to its right. what should I do to overcome this problem, **Note: I dont want to hide text (ellipsis)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the heights of your floated divs are different... you can either give your divs a fixed height to make room for the second line of text:

```
.movie_item {
    height: 220px;
}
```

See ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bodxs2d/2/)***.

...or considering not using bootstrap and removing the float on the divs. You could for example use `display: flex;` instead (see [w3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) and [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

For example, something like the following on your containing div:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

See ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bodxs2d/)*** (`.row` replaced with `.wrap` to avoid bootstrap styles).

Comment: You may have to use the `-webkit-` prefix for older versions of android, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

Comment: It looks like older versions of android do not support the flex-wrap property. I would post the details as a new question to see if anyone else has some good alternatives. If not, you may have to revert to fixed heights and cutting off overflow.

Comment: my android version is 4.2.2, not too older